# Making Storyboards into resources that can be used by multiple controls in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, animation

I have a working animation, now I am placing it in `Apps.xaml` under `application.Resources`, with all necessary bindings but it doesn't work. Am I missing something in the binding process? What is the proper way to bind the `Storyboard.Targetname`?

```xml
<Storyboard x:Key="RotateIn">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="button2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-100"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="button2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="button2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform" 
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                                 By="10"        
                                                 To="360" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.7" 
                                                 FillBehavior="Stop" />
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        </Storyboard>
```

```xml
<Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btn2" Width="150" Height="150" Background="gray">
                <StackPanel >
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource img2}" x:Name="button2" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>Rotate In</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

Above is my working animation created for a single Control. However, when I tried to make it into a resource where it can be reused like 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496028/place-storyboard-in-application-resources) , (H.B.)'s answer :

```xml
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Storyboard x:Key="BindingRotate" x:Shared="False">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="{DynamicResource AnimationTarget}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-100"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="{DynamicResource AnimationTarget}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="{DynamicResource AnimationTarget}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="{DynamicResource AnimationTarget1}"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                                 By="10"        
                                                 To="360" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.7" 
                                                 FillBehavior="Stop" />
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="{DynamicResource AnimationTarget2}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="90"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            </Storyboard>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
```

```xml
<Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btn2" Width="150" Height="150" Background="gray">
                <StackPanel >
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource img2}" x:Name="button2" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                        <Image.Resources>
                            <sys:String x:Key="AnimationTarget">button</sys:String>
                        </Image.Resources>
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" x:Name="AnimationTarget1">

                                </RotateTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Text="Rotate In">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Expand In">
                            <TextBlock.Resources>
                                <sys:String x:Key="AnimationTarget2">button</sys:String>
                            </TextBlock.Resources>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BindingRotate}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
```

> ''[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[3].(2)'.'

Exception is all I get. I followed exactly what was stated in the answer. Please let me know what is missing in my binding as I could not find related topic.

Another question, is there any way for me to set

```
<sys:String x:Key="AnimationTarget1">button</sys:String>
```

into 
`<RotateTransform.Resources>`
 as I did to other controls? Thank you for your time. I am still quite new to WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the resources that you are referring to in your `Storyboard`, i.e. `AnimationTarget`, `AnimationTarget1` and `AnimationTarget2`, in the `Resources` property of the `Button` where the `EventTrigger` is defined. This works for me:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btn2" Width="150" Height="150" Background="gray">
    <Button.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="AnimationTarget">button2</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="AnimationTarget1">AnimatedRotateTransform</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="AnimationTarget2">button2</sys:String>
    </Button.Resources>
    <StackPanel >
        <Image Source="{StaticResource img2}" x:Name="button2" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Text="Rotate In">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Expand In" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BindingRotate}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```